# Need to execute code behind on a regular hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, code-behind

I have a strange situation.  I have a website where hyperlinks are dynamically generated (as user controls) which have the `target` attribute set to `_blank` as I need it to open in a new window. Due to the nature of what the new page is displaying I need to audit when the user clicks on it.  I already have auditing functionality set up so I am looking for a way to run code before the link opens the new page.

If it was in internal page on the same site i could simply have the hyperlink as a command button which runs the audit code and then does a `Response.Redirect()`.

I don't have any control over the target pages because they are on a different website. I would be interested to her how others have done this and whether it's possible to do it in the way that I've explained!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your links to be a handler on your site that does the auditing and then redirects. So your links would be something like

```
<a href="/MyAuditingHandler.ashx?targetUrl=http://www.externalsite.com" target="_blank"></a>
```

Your handler audits, reads the `targetUrl` parameter and then redirects.

Comment: Of course, I had totally missed that I could have the handler itself as a popup

Answer (score 1):

You can still do the `Response.Redirect()` technique, or am I missing something here? Have the real hyperlinks passed as parameters to your audit page...

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to open the link in a new window (tab) 
I would suggest a JavaScript Window.Open and before that a AJAX call for your Audit. This will be must fast and better UX.

Comment: Response.Redirect is terrible interm of UX as well as server load.